# CSPack RemotingException while packaging Cloud service project with MSBuild

Tags: powershell, azure, msbuild, cspack

I have a powershell script that is packaging our builds and deploys them to Azure Cloud Services. This script was running without any problem with SDK 2.3, but when we upgraded to SDK 2.5 we started receiving the following error while building the project:

```
CorePublish:
  CorePublish: PackageWebRole = True
  Publishing starting...
  RolePlugins       is 
  Importedmodules is 
  Publishing to 'bin\Release\app.publish\'
  Creating directory "bin\Release\app.publish\".
  TargetServiceDefinition is bin\Release\ServiceDefinition.csdef
  TargetServiceConfiguration is bin\Release\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
  Roles is E:\Preview\temp\Azure\obj\Release\App\
error MSB4018: The "CSPack" task failed unexpectedly. 
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Object '/54628d54_42c6_4d39_bc4c_958b6bfaeb90/6y8efa6v6y8omskqeetyix8g_4.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server. 
   at System.IO.FileStream.get_CanRead() 
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.CheckFileAccessParameter(Stream stream, FileAccess access) 
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access) 
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackagePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access) 
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access) 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.Utils.CopyFullStreamToPart(Stream source, PackagePart part, PackageManifest manifest) 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.PackageCreator.CreateRolePackages(ModelProcessor modelProcessor, PackageManifest applicationManifest, Package applicationPackage) 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.PackageCreator.CreatePackage(Stream outputStream, Action`1 postProcess, PackageRestrictions restrictions) 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.ServiceApplicationPackage.CreateServiceApplicationPackage(String serviceModelFileName, String serviceDescriptionFile, Stream output, IPackageSecurity encrypt, Dictionary`2 namedStreamCollection, String userInfo, EventHandler`1 rolePackagePartAddedHandler) 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.PackageCreator.CreateServiceApplicationPackage(String serviceRdFilePath, String processedServiceDefinitionFile, FileStream packageStream, Dictionary`2 namedStreams, Dictionary`2 rolesDictionary) 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.PackageCreator.CreateServiceApplicationPackage(String serviceRdFilePath, String processedServiceDefinitionFile, FileStream packageStream, Dictionary`2 namedStreams, Dictionary`2 rolesDictionary) 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.CSPack.TryCreatePackage(ServiceDefinitionModel sm) 
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.CSPack.Execute() 
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() 
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
```

It is running on Windows Server 2008 R2, using MSBuild from VS2013 and the MSBuild is runnin like this parameters (from powershell):

```
& $msBuildPath "$tempPath\Azure\Azure.ccproj" /p:TargetProfile=Cloud /p:Configuration=Release /target:publish /flp:"Verbosity=quiet;logfile=E:\AzurePreview\msbuild.log"
I could not find anything connected to this issue.
```

I even tried to remove all traces of VS, SDKs and tools that might be connected to powershell, VS or Azure in general and installed the necessary parts again rebut nothing helped.

Could you please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this issue with Microsoft support, I was able to package the project using CSPack command line tool, so I'm using this as a workaround.

**Edit:**
This issue seems fixed in Azure SDK 2.7